# Strange dots are displayed in swiper js

Tags: swiper.js

I'm experimenting Swiper js library. I managed to get it working. But some strange dots are shown when the slides wraps from the last to the first and the problem is happening when loop attribute is set to true.

[The strange dots are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUFTl.png)

Here is the html code. Note that loop attrib is set to true.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .swiper {
            width: 600px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .page1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #443321;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <!-- Slider main container -->
    <div class="swiper">
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="page1">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
        </div>
        <!-- If we need pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    
        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    <script>
        const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            // Optional parameters
            direction: 'horizontal',
            loop: true,
            loopedSlides: 50,
            observer: true,
            obsereParents: true,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 30,

            // If we need pagination
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },

            // Navigation arrows
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },

        });
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine with no `...`. You either didn't post everything, or its a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    ...
```

I had this problem too. Your html code is generating those dots, after the Slide 3 element. It looks like the three dots may have been there when you copy/pasted a code snippet. Remove them and your problem will disappear

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the space between the slides and place a slide data in div and give margin on two sides of the div. By using this the box shadow will not cut.

[image]